# Why does giving a type to the apply method on Series does what it does?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I had this problem recently, where you have a `pandas.Series` of `tuples`, e.g. `my_series = [(a, b), (c, d), (e, f) … ]`, and you want to make a `DataFrame` out of it, of the following form:

```
col1 col2
a    b
c    d
e    f
…
```

Now, *I found a solution*, but I don’t understand *why* it works.

It is simply `my_series.apply(pandas.Series)`. The doc doesn’t really help in that regard. Whey does giving a type to the `apply` method yield such a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` (both on GroupBy objects and on Series/DataFrames) is a flexible method and based on the return value of the function that you pass to it, it might change the resulting data structure to a more useful one. Here's the relevant parts from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply):

> apply on a Series can operate on a returned value from the applied
>   function, that is itself a series, and possibly upcast the result to a
>   DataFrame

---

> apply can act as a reducer, transformer, or filter function,
>   depending on exactly what is passed to it. So depending on the path
>   taken, and exactly what you are grouping. Thus the grouped columns(s)
>   may be included in the output as well as set the indices.

(This one is for GroupBy.apply but the same holds for Series.apply. It can act as a reducer or a transformer.)

In your example, it calls the Series constructor on each element of the Series. (`pd.Series(('a', 'b'))`, `pd.Series(('c', 'd'))` and so on). In the end you have a collection of Series with the same indices so it returns a DataFrame.

Here's another (useful) example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})

df
Out[2]: 
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

df.apply(lambda x: x.describe())
Out[3]: 
         a    b
count  3.0  3.0
mean   2.0  5.0
std    1.0  1.0
min    1.0  4.0
25%    1.5  4.5
50%    2.0  5.0
75%    2.5  5.5
max    3.0  6.0
```

If it didn't unpack the result I would have a Series which holds another Series for each column. Of course in this example you are better off with `df.describe()` but your custom function can return a Series and pandas in that case can give you a DataFrame so that it is tidier and easier to work with.

If you want to be explicit, you can convert the Series to a list and call the DataFrame constructor:

```
ser = pd.Series([('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')])

ser
Out[10]: 
0    (a, b)
1    (c, d)
2    (e, f)
dtype: object

ser.tolist()
Out[11]: [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]

pd.DataFrame(ser.tolist())
Out[12]: 
   0  1
0  a  b
1  c  d
2  e  f
```

This is my preferred way of unpacking elements in a Series.

Comment: Thank you sir, this answered very well to my question.